# In Android, preinstalled apps are always disable to uninstall?

Tags: android, uninstallation

Just that, I like to know is always all the preinstalled apps are with the uninstall button disable in Android.

Comment: preinstalled app is under the android `system/app` path, so except you got the root privilege, you can't uninstall them.

Comment: So it means that if I install an APK trought the RecoveryMode I'll give an uninstallable app right?, because this is I'm looking for.

Comment: Normally, pre-insalled app is push into the system.img before they were flashed to the device.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, some of the pre-installed apps can't be uninstalled without rooting your phone using cyanogenmod or rooting your phone.

Comment: I don't want to uninstall an preinstalled app.
I want to install an app with this feature of "no uninstall"... so I understand I need to install an APK  throught the RecoveryMode, right?

Comment: You want to install an app that is uninstallable?  How do you plan on releasing this app?  I doubt this is possible for a regular app.

Comment: I don't want to release the app in the Android Market or whatever way for share the app. I have a direct client where he wants install the app with this characteristic only for 20 devices. It means I can work directly with this devices.

Answer (score 0):

Some pre-installed applications can be uninstalled. For example in Android 4 (ICS) you can go to Settings -> Apps and select the "All" tab. There you can uninstall some of the preinstalled software.

Comment: What do you mean with some preinstalled apps?, those apps are really installed since the OEM launches the device?? I don't wan't to uninstall an preinstalled app, I want to install an app with this option of "no uninstall" by the user. And I understand for this I need to install the APK throught the RecoveryMode using an "update.zip"... right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Android shouldn't let you do that. The user must always have the right to uninstall an app

Comment: I understand the reasons for allow de uninstall and the idea of how the apps should be. But, in this case one person (for her employees) wants a uninstallable app.

Comment: I understand that... could be a possibility to "inform" or send an email to the person when the person uninstall the application? I mean, when the person wants to uninstall it the application first sends an email? I'm still a newbie in Android, so this is just an idea...

Comment: Thats is a good idea Christian, but for my purpose is necessary disable this option and I'm trying to know how Google and the carriers do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Root the phone, put the APK into the `/system/app` folder and then unroot the phone. This is possible on a Droid 4 at least in theory. Not sure about other hardware models. If you can root and unroot the phones it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the Device manufacturer. They have the possibility to install the app in any way they like before they freeze the image and flash it to the hardware in the factory.

For example some of the Branded apps might be installed under system privileges, but some of the more "friendly recommendation" apps might be free to uninstall.

Answer (score -1):

From what i understand in ics apps in usolder can be uninsfreeled, apps in system folder instead of uninstall the button reads disable. Except for only s slight few only, these apps are reQuired by the os for the user to be able to"enable" a disable App, so i think i the app needs to be signed by the room cooker our needs top have a intent in the manifest like a launcher or home app (since if you disable your home launcher you bricked your phone, so you can't disable it, but if you give your app a intent label of copied from the Android source launcher then the phone will think it's a launcher, and not let you disable it, you will prob have to set the home launcher back to be default or Android will ask you witch launcher too use Every time user hits the home button, i was looking for the same answer found this page
[Android 4.0 Api to Disable Apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592174/android-4-0-api-to-disable-apk) Witch gave me the idea, currently thus reply is closest I've come to impinging the idea, i well be trying it soon, if you beat me to it, let me know tour results, and i well do the same. 
 And to install a app in /system/app a uninstall.zip won't do it, you need too root the phone, install the app, xfer it to system (i use system/app mover available in the play store free, the too secure ot Unindtsll app mover, and unroot, any way good luck. 
P.s. I'm Not a Dev, i just understand the format format of the app language, and can c effectivly search for info, so please no code questions. i can't answer them, but google can.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be preferred to add some line breaks here and there to make the post more readable.

Comment: How is the proporsal that you have? :)